# Chromium wakes up 300 times a second

Tags: chromium, powertop

If I've got a gmail tab open and nothing else, running powertop shows

```
Wakeups-from-idle per second : 414.5    interval: 30.0s
no ACPI power usage estimate available
Top causes for wakeups:
  61.9% (1023.8)   chromium-browse
```

Is this bad and if so what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same on my system.  I think it has to do with how GMail has an automated refresh system that runs pretty often.  I don't think it's going to be an issue for ya, it hasnt broken my system yet.  :P

Comment: It's not just Gmail: the Google search page does it too even with the **instant** off. But interestingly, Bing behaves itself ..

Comment: @daithib8 but that's Bing... and by comparison, Bing is horrible as a search engine ;P